# A verbatim column in tabular environment

Tags: tables, verbatim

I want to build a table with a column of verbatim, but I don't want to use \verb command for every line (too many rows), how should I do it? I tried to use array package to define new column type but unsuccessful, anyone can shed some light? An example of what I wanna achieve:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l l}
\verb|some text here| & some text here \\
\verb|some text here| & some text here \\
\verb|some text here| & some text here \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

- I need verbatim (instead of just `begin{tabular}{>{\ttfamily}l<{\ttfamily}}` as the first row contained many reserved characters.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With the `shortvrb` package you might abbreviate to `|text|` instead of `\verb|text|`, but not less than this. Just think to the fact that you need some way for TeX to understand where the verbatim text ends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Verbatim mode is really very special. In some cases one can use the `&` for delimiting an argument (see the `collcell` package), but with verbatim this becomes essentially impossible, because the `&` is *not* the cell delimiter any more as soon as verbatim mode is started.

The `shortvrb` package allows to say

```
\MakeShortVerb{\|}
```

thereby declaring that, from the point on, `|...|` is equivalent to `\verb|...|`. Of course you'll need `\verb+...+` (or similar) if the verbatim text contains `|`.

Note however that this will make `|` illegal in math, but there's the substitute `\vert` (or better the pair `\lvert` and `\rvert` provided by `amsmath`) for it.

So the best you can have is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shortvrb}

\MakeShortVerb{\|}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l l}
|some % text here| & some text here \\
|some $ text here| & some text here \\
|some { text here| & some text here \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In principle, one *could* use `&` as the verbatim delimiter, and then insert another `&` at the end of the verbatim text, _e.g._, `\newcommand*\SetUpVerbCol{\toks@\expandafter{\verb@egroup &}\edef\verb@egroup{\the\toks@}\verb &}`, followed by, say, `\begin{tabular}{l>{\SetUpVerbCol}ll}Normal text &verb_text^{$& more text that uses \verb|\verb|\\ … \end{tabular}`.  And indeed this works, **if…** the first token in the verbatim column is *not* a control sequence (say, `\foo`), because otherwise TeX tries to expand it as soon as it scans the opening `&`, and this cannot be avoided in any way!