# Inserting verbatim inside a table with <> column-specifiers

Tags: tables, verbatim

I want to draw a table with two columns: the first one contains some `LaTeX` commands and the second one its preview. Instead of inserting the command `\verb++` in each row, I want to benefit from `<>` column-specifiers. But this results on compilation errors. Please consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
 \begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
  %\begin{tabular}{>{\verb+}l<{+}l} <--- what I want to use
   \verb+\LaTeX+    & \LaTeX
  \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207977/197451

**First method with collectcell and detokenise**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,collcell}
\newcommand{\myverb}[1]{\ttfamily\detokenize{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ >{\collectcell\myverb}l<{\endcollectcell} l }
  PI_all_data_BBB_M15X.pdf     & Results for \verb=BBB= model with profile plots \\
  PI_all_data_BetaBin_M15X.pdf & Results for \verb=BetaBin= model with profile plots \\
  PI_all_data_BinLNB_M15X.pdf  & Results for \verb=BinLNB= model with profile plots \\
  PI_all_data_Bin_M15X.pdf     & Results for \verb=Bin= model with profile plots \\
  PI_all_data_LogGamma_M15X.pdf& Results for \verb=LogGamma= model with profile plots \\
  PI_all_data_TwoBin_M15X.pdf  & Results for \verb=TwoBin= model with profile plots
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Second method with shortvrb package**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shortvrb}

\MakeShortVerb{\|}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l l}
|some % text here| & some text here \\
|some $ text here| & some text here \\
|some { text here| & some text here \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297214/197451